# Configuring Auth0 authentication on Google App Engine Standard and the Cloud Endpoints Frameworks with Python

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, auth0, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am using [Cloud Endpoints Frameworks with Python](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks) in a Google Cloud App Engine Standard environment to provide an API.

As far as I can tell, I should be able to use python decorators from the Endpoints Frameworks in combination with the endpointscfg.py command-line tool to automatically set up token-based authentication with Auth0; the endpointscfg.py command-line automatically creates the openapi.json file that is used to configure the Google Endpoints proxy.

Here's an example of my decorator for an API that echos stuff back:

```
# # [START echo_api]
@endpoints.api(
    name='echo',
    version=_VERSION,
    api_key_required=True,
    audiences={'auth0': ['https://echo.<my-project>.appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo']},
    issuers={'auth0': endpoints.Issuer(
        'https://<my-project>.auth0.com',
        'https://<my-project>.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json')}
)
class EchoApi(remote.Service):
    ...
```

When I run the endpointscfg.py command-line tool, I get something in my openapi.json file that looks about right:

```
"paths": {
    "/echo/v1/echo": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "EchoApi_echo",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainEchoRequest"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainEchoResponse"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "api_key": [],
            "auth0_jwt": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }

"securityDefinitions": {
    "api_key": {
      "in": "query",
      "name": "key",
      "type": "apiKey"
    },
    "auth0_jwt": {
      "authorizationUrl": "https://<my-project>.auth0.com/authorize",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "type": "oauth2",
      "x-google-issuer": "https://<my-project>.auth0.com",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://<my-project>.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json",
      "x-google-audiences": "https://echo.<my-project>.appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo"
    }
  }
```

So, the problem is that this set-up appears to do nothing and does not check incoming tokens to prevent access if no token is present or if the token is invalid.

I have been able to set-up manual processing of the bearer token within the API echo function using the python-jose library (sorry if it's not well done, but I'm just testing and comments are welcome):

```
authorization_header = self.request_state.headers.get('authorization')
    if authorization_header is not None:
        if authorization_header.startswith('Bearer '):
            access_token = authorization_header[7:]
            logging.info(access_token)
        else:
            logging.error("Authorization header did not start with 'Bearer '!")
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException(
                    "Authentication failed (improperly formatted authorization header).")
        else:
            logging.error("Authorization header did not start with 'Bearer '!")
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException("Authentication failed (bearer token not found).")

r = urlfetch.fetch(_JWKS_URL)
jwks_content = json.loads(r.content)
keys = jwks_content['keys']
public_key = jwk.construct(keys[0])
logging.info(public_key)

message, encoded_signature = str(access_token).rsplit('.', 1)
# decode the signature
decoded_signature = base64url_decode(encoded_signature.encode('utf-8'))
# verify the signature
if not public_key.verify(message.encode("utf8"), decoded_signature):
    logging.warning('Signature verification failed')
    raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException("Authentication failed (invalid signature).")
else:
    logging.info('Signature successfully verified')

claims = jwt.get_unverified_claims(access_token)
# additionally we can verify the token expiration
if time.time() > claims['exp']:
    logging.warning('Token is expired')
    raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException("Authentication failed (token expired).")
# and the Audience  (use claims['client_id'] if verifying an access token)
if claims['aud'] != _APP_CLIENT_ID:
    logging.warning('Token was not issued for this audience')
    raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException("Authentication failed (incorrect audience).")
# now we can use the claims
logging.info(claims)
```

This code works, but I assumed that the whole point of setting up the decorator and configuring the openapi.json file was to off-load these checks to the proxy so that only valid tokens hit my code.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
It may be that I need to check endpoints.get_current_user() in my code to control access. However, I have just noticed the following in my logs:

```
Cannot decode and verify the auth token. The backend will not be able to retrieve user info (/base/data/home/apps/e~<my-project>/echo:alpha23.414400469228485401/lib/endpoints_management/control/wsgi.py:643)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~<my-project>/echo:alpha23.414400469228485401/lib/endpoints_management/control/wsgi.py", line 640, in __call__
    service_name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~<my-project>/echo:alpha23.414400469228485401/lib/endpoints_management/auth/tokens.py", line 75, in authenticate
    error)
UnauthenticatedException: (u'Cannot decode the auth token', UnauthenticatedException(u'Cannot find the `jwks_uri` for issuer https://<my-project>.auth0.com/: either the issuer is unknown or the OpenID discovery failed',))
```

However, I think everything is configured ok. Any idea why 'jwks_uri' cannot be found despite the fact that path in the openapi.json file is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the current maintainer of these Frameworks. You do need to check `endpoints.get_current_user()` to control access, yes. I'm working on a feature to make this much simpler.

As for that UnauthenticatedException, you can ignore it. That's coming from the 'management framework', which attempts to check auth tokens even though it's not involved in the Frameworks' oauth security (only the api key security).